# having trouble with mysqli query default value

Tags: php, mysqli

i am working with mysqli query and i want to set default value for perticular column getting that value from variable 
i have tried a lot i could not get any solution on internet
if there is any expert with mysqli help me out of this
$route_name, $from, $to value of this variable should be take as  default value
here is my query

```
CREATE TABLE $route_table_name (
route_id INT(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
bus_id INT(11),
route_name VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT $route_name,
route_from VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT $from,
route_to VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT $to
)
```

Comment: Show us the full PHP that runs this query, including the mysqli / PDO command, and the quotes / syntax, and the values of the variables.

Comment: Well, what exactly is the problem? Where's the code that sets those variables? Have you checked that the values of those variables are as expected? What other debugging have you done?

Comment: taking values from form and values are getting proper but table is not getting created                                                                              if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$route_name = $_POST['route_name'];
$from = $_POST['from'];
$to = $_POST['to'];}

Comment: You should probably use single quotes for the values `$route_name` to `'$route_name'` etc.

Comment: i tried that also but did not worked

Comment: If the table is not being created, then I guarantee that some sort of error is being thrown. Use the proper error reporting/handling features provided by whatever db library you are using to find out exactly what's wrong.  PHP and MySQL generally do a pretty good job showing you where your problem is, you just have to check for it.

Comment: These variables are coming from POST args? Oh dear. I sure hope you trust whomever is using the form.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query($connection,"CREATE TABLE `".$route_table_name."` (
route_id INT(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
bus_id INT(11),
route_name VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT `".$route_name."`,
route_from VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT `".$from."`,
route_to VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT `".$to."`
)");
```

Make sure values are passing

Comment: I dont think you want backticks around the default values and if you remember that `$vars` are automatically expanded inside a double quoted string you can also make that a lot easier to read by removing some unnecessary concatenation

Answer (score 0):

i use this and now its working fine thanks a lot
CREATE TABLE $route_table_name (
route_id INT(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
bus_id INT(11),
route_name VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT '$route_name',
route_from VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT '$from',
route_to VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT '$to'
)